# How can one protect from malicious code inside a website?

Tags: wordpress, security

I have recently taken ownership of an Wordpress website, after having a long dispute with the previous developer.

Because of this, I want to make sure that he didn't left some malicious code inside - to steal passwords, change things in the database, remove files ....

So the question is that instead of checking each file inside (Wordpress core, plugins, and so on) - what other possibilities I have to make sure that there is no threat? How can one protect himself from an inside attack?

I know that this can be difficult to answer, but maybe you have some past experience with this kind of situations...

Comment: You might better ask this question at [webmasters.SE] or [security.SE]

Comment: You almost can't, unless you want to check every code in there, and be _very_ clear on what it does _exactly_. If the trust just isn't there, you're better of making a fresh install of the wordpress package & possible plugins from trusted sources, which would mean you only have to check custom code for the project, which would still be a chore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a stock installation of Wordpress, you can use "diff" or a similar file-comparison tool to compare your installation against the official distribution to see what changes, if any, have been made.

After you've done that and made sure you understand the purpose of any changes, you'll need to go over the configuration, account settings, and the like to make sure there aren't any backdoors or other security holes deliberately left behind.

Comment: Using "diff" approach is a good one (assuming that no big changes were done to the code).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only definitive safe answer I can offer is a fresh install, followed by a copy of TEXT content into the new site. Non-text-content items you want to retain will need to be either rewritten or thoroughly vetted.